# Colours are not being displayed on buttons in calculator - why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want them to be dark grey and have tried different colours but none are working it just displays all of them as light grey. here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

cal = Tk()
cal.title("CALCULATOR")
operator=""
text_Input =StringVar()

txtDisplay= Entry(cal,font=('arial',20,'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30,insertwidth=4,
                  bg="purple", justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)

btn7=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('aerial', 20,'bold'),
            text="7", bg="grey").grid(row=1,column=0)

btn8=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('aerial', 20,'bold'),
            text="8", bg="grey").grid(row=1,column=1)

btn9=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('aerial', 20,'bold'),
            text="9", bg="grey").grid(row=1,column=2)

Addition=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('aerial', 20,'bold'),
                text="+", bg="orange").grid(row=1,column=3)

cal.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you on OSX? That platform doesn't let you set the color of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background color of the buttons should do, for example, the following code for the btn7, could be

```
btn7=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('aerial', 20,'bold'),
            text="7", bg="gray25").grid(row=1,column=0)
```

which would make it a dark shade of gray.
Here is a table of all the colors in tkinker:
http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Color_Charts_for_TKinter

I also saw you are using mac, and found the following post, in which someone's color wasn't working on mac.
[Border and Background color not showing in mac [python -Tkinter]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545215/border-and-background-color-not-showing-in-mac-python-tkinter?rq=1)

Comment: You can't change the background or border of buttons on OSX due to platform constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To get a different shade of grey, I suggest explicitly specifying the color RGB components of the color you want, that way you can have any one you want instead of being restricted to those to which tkinter has given names. You can do this in tkinter using them as hexidecimal digits in a specially formatted string (here's some [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/colors.html)).

I've demonstrate this in the code below and ***also fixed another problem*** I noticed with how you're calling the `grid()` geometry manager. It always returns `None`, so your code is setting all widget variables to that value not to the widget instances like you think. See [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) .

To avoid that problem you need to call it separately after creating the widgets as also shown.

On a final note: I *strongly* suggest you read and begin following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

```
from tkinter import *


BTN_COLOR = '#404040'  # Dark grey.

cal = Tk()
cal.title("CALCULATOR")
operator = " "
text_Input = StringVar()

txtDisplay = Entry(cal, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30,
                   insertwidth=4, bg="purple", justify='right')
txtDisplay.grid(columnspan=4)

btn7 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('aerial', 20, 'bold'),
              text="7", bg=BTN_COLOR)
btn7.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn8 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('aerial', 20, 'bold'),
              text="8", bg=BTN_COLOR)
btn8.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn9 = Button(cal, padx=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=('aerial', 20, 'bold'),
              text="9", bg=BTN_COLOR)
btn9.grid(row=1, column=2)

Addition = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('aerial', 20, 'bold'),
                  text="+", bg="orange")
Addition.grid(row=1, column=3)

cal.mainloop()
```

Screenshot showing result:

[image: Screenshot showing dark grey buttons]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error is that "grey" isn't a colour on tkinter. The link I have added is a chart with all possible colours without hex codes.

http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Color_Charts_for_TKinter